# Getting the latest sheet and erasing the old one

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the latest sheet and erase the older sheet but cant get a value for save variable.

The first loop is for storing a value on a two dimension array. the second loop is for getting the latest sheet.

```
Sub WorksheetEraseOld()
    Dim ShtNames() As String
    Dim SaveSheet As String
    ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)
    For i = 1 To Sheets.count
        ShtNames(i) = Sheets(i).Name
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)
    For J = 1 To Sheets.count
        If J = Sheets.count Then Exit For
        Range("A1").Value = Val(Left(ShtNames(J), 4))
        Range("B1").Value = Val(Left(ShtNames(J + 1), 4))
        MsgBox ("Content of SaveSheet is " & SaveSheet)
        SaveSheet = ShtNames(J)
        If Val(Left(SaveSheet, 4)) < Val(Left(ShtNames(J + 1), 4)) Then SaveSheet = ShtNames(J + 1)
    Next J
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For J = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If J = Sheets.Count Then Exit For
Next J
Range("A1").Value = Val(Left(ShtNames(J), 4))
Range("B1").Value = Val(Left(ShtNames(J + 1), 4))
MsgBox ("Content of SaveSheet is " & SaveSheet)
SaveSheet = ShtNames(J)
If Val(Left(SaveSheet, 4)) < Val(Left(ShtNames(J + 1), 4)) Then SaveSheet = ShtNames(J + 1)
```